# Is there any reason to wait before adding tag usage guidance?

Tags: discussion

Most of our tags currently have no usage guidance. Looking at existing stacks I often notice tags with no guidance.

Is there any benefit in us waiting to do this? For example will waiting until tags are used dozens of times help us create more useful guidance (that relates to actual tag usage) than if we created guidance now?

Comment: I gave the Ethereum.SE some advice about tags when they set out here: [Good Tags now save a lot of work later!](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/70/235). You may find it useful to this discussion as well.

Comment: @murch that post was very helpful. It sounds like the process is much easier if tackled early

Comment: @SebastianUllrich: Yes, it probably is. However, it is a process that needs to be reevaluated from time to time. Depending on how the question corpus develops it may make sense to split up tags over time, e.g. when they broaden in scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been working on the tags and see no reason to wait.

I have two follow up questions:

1. Are tags pseudonyms generally encouraged or should they be avoided (encouraging users to find and use the most popular tag)?
2. Should abbreviations be used? Monero has a sync tag while Bitcoin SE has a synchronization tag. Which is preferable?

Answer (score 5):

Users should be encouraged to create tag usage guidance any time they use a tag that does not yet have it. For existing tags, we should focus on adding guidance for tags that have already been used multiple times.