# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer to say they accept/decline the nomination. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following their acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://monero.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://monero.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Hey Robert, I was just wondering what's the next step here.

Comment: @Murch I'll be giving an update soon.

Answer (score 42):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate User36303.

User36303 has been the most active person on this Stack so far (by far according to posted and accepted answers). In my opinion the answers this person provides are of extremely high quality. This user also has helped with moderating the site and appears motivated to maintain high quality content.

```
I accept this nomination.

Hi, I am User36303, and I like privacy.
The moderator guidelines seem OK to me, and I plan to be here for the foreseeable future.
```

Answer (score 40):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

fluffyponyza is the most visible Monero developer and has made countless public appearances educating people about blockchain tech and privacy. Having him as a moderator will enhance the credibility of this project.

As a Kovri developer he is also best positioned to determine which Kovri  questions belong here and which questions might better belong on the I2P stackexchange site that will also start beta soon.

**Edit from fluffypony:**

> I accept this nomination, and will endeavour to contribute to the growth and structure of this Stack. I'm in UTC +2, so I'm normally on at different times to a lot of the other visitors:)

Comment: I accept the nomination, and will endeavour to contribute to the growth and structure of this Stack.

Comment: Oh just noticed I'm supposed to edit the nomination, my bad.

Answer (score 34):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate Smart Kid because he is quite active here and is motivated to make this Stack Exchange site a success. He referred many people to the site when it was in the commitment stage and helped ensure that they joined private beta once it began.

He may be fairly new to StackExchange but has spent a lot of time over the last month studying. Now appearing to have a solid grasp of how SE works, he is very helpful in explaining things to others. At the same time he is humble enough to know when to ask for help.

**Edit from Smart Kid:**

> I accept this nomination and am willing to spend a significant amount of time on the effort. I actively promoted this proposal while it was in Area51 and want to see it succeed.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate 5chdn because we could use the experience of someone who has experience as an active moderator on another SE cryptocurrency [site](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/87/5chdn).

Comment: Thanks for the nomination. I am accepting it under the terms that I am putting myself here in a backup slot. If you need additional help to maintain and promote this beta site, I'm available. However, if you find enough engaged users from within this active private beta community, I'm fine with _just_ helping out without the little diamond. You may have noticed, I've _only_ been active on monero meta so far.

Comment: @5chdn Your recent meta post about closing and voting was very helpful. Thank you for being a great resource for us.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate 2quick 4u

This nominee would be a good choice because he's been active on the private beta since day 1, demonstrating a broad knowledge on various topics related to monero. He's also actively participating in the monero meta.

Comment: Thank you for the nomination! I would be willing to help moderate in the future if another person is needed. However with the current need for 3 moderators, I am very happy with the 3 candidates above who have already accepted their nomination.

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand and agree, but I thought it's good to have a "Plan B" since the other nominees are all busy with other monero stuff too. So in case of a needed future reorganisation of the SE moderation we should have provably knowledgeable people like you ready to jump in.

Comment: It's always good to have more nominations than moderator spots available. However, if you check the ethereum beta site, you will notice we have four moderators. So I think it's based on activity of the site and you sometimes get more than three candidates assigned to the task.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I would like to nominate dEBRUYNE as another candidate with both the technical skills and willingness to do a great job as a moderator. Among his many contributions to the Monero community has been his great work as a [moderator](https://www.reddit.com/user/dEBRUYNE_1) of [r/Monero](https://www.reddit.com/r/monero)

He is knowledgeable, helpful, level-headed and sure to be an asset to this stack.

Comment: I'll gladly accept this nomination.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Based on above comments about it being preferable to have more nominations that the number of moderators desired, I will self nominate as a backup candidate.

I supported this [prior proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96062/monero) before I created this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98617?phase=definition) on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/150962/studycrypto) which I worked very hard to support. Essentially I have been around from the beginning and am committed to helping grow this Stack.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate Murch because of his vast experience as a moderator of Bitcoin SE. He has a proven willingness to help advise both our [site](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19/138) and [Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/2137) based on that experience.

Comment: Thank you, user22576. However, I decline this nomination. I'm not sufficiently engaged with this community and topic to be an effective moderator for your site. Still, I'd be happy to contribute to meta when I I can provide useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Nominating Ilya Kitaev because soon many people will come here with GUI questions. Ilya is in the best position to answer and moderate questions about the GUI he helped build.

Comment: Since he has not a meta account, he wont be able to accept the nomination (yet).